# Can't build setup?

Tags: visual-studio

I have a Deployment Project for my Visual Studio 2015 program which use to build a setup package when I right clicked on it in the Solution Explorer and went to Build.  Now I get "Build Failed" but absolutely no error message as to why.

I have Entire Solution selected in the Error List and Build + Intellisense for the filter but nothing shows.  I read a lot but nothing ever helps.  I can build my C# console application fine, but not the setup package.

So I can't build my setup, its ridiculous and I was hoping someone could help.

VS 14.0.25123.00 Update 2

Comment: Did you check the output window for build?

Comment: Visual Studio stopped supporting deployment projects after VS2010.  There is a "Visual Studio Installer Projects" extension that is intended to replace it, but I don't know if it works with the same project format.

Comment: I'm assuming the Output Window is the Error list, yes I watch that, it shows nothing.   thats where errors usually go.  And yes, its an extension I use, but it worked fine before.  And I had this problem before even and I did something to fix it but forget what the hell I did.  I thought this might be a thing people knew about.

Comment: I found, the error was in an Output window, as opposed to the Error List.  Thanks.